# binary function in python cuts the zeros

Tags: python

I want to generate binary list of numbers in python as in below:

```
'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011', '4':'0100', '5':'0101',
'6':'0110', '7':'0111', '8':'1000', '9':'1001' .....
```

I wrote small code for doing this job, but when I run that I got a result like this:
`'0':'0', '1':'1', '2':'10', '3':'11', '4':'100', '5':'101',
 '6':'110', '7':'111', '8':'1000', '9':'1001' .....`
How can I do that bin() didn't cut all zeros at the start. Thank you for reading. My code:

```
my_number = int(input("Please enter number"))


    for i in range(0,2**my_number):
        print(bin(i)[2:])
```

Comment: You `ljust()` it with zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2:

```
import math
n = int(input("Please enter a number "))
x = int(math.ceil(math.log(n,2)))
print ", ".join(['\'{0}\':\'{0:0{1}b}\''.format(i,x) for i in range(n)])
```

Python 3:

```
import math
n = int(input("Please enter a number "))
print(", ".join([f'\'{i}\':\'{i:0{math.ceil(math.log(n,2))}b}\'' for i in range(n)]))
```

Gives the desired output:

```
'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010', '3':'0011', '4':'0100', '5':'0101', '6':'0110', '7':'0111', '8':'1000', '9':'1001'
```

Comment: Thanks for all for the response. In the case if I will use ':04d' it will return only for 4 point binary numbers. But in my case I don't know upper bond of the numbers. I mean lets say if I will enter 1342 or 4321 but my upper bond of numbers are 123456 anyway I will not get the result which I want. So how can I do this? Thank you for reading

Answer (score 3):

Use *string formatting* for this:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(f"{i:04b}")
...
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
```

Note, I'm using Python 3.6 f-strings, but you can always use the `.format` method.

Answer (score 0):

**for numbers**

```
x = 11
print ("%04d"%x)
# or
print ("{0:04d}".format(x))
```

**for strings**

```
x = "11"
print (x.zfill(4))
```